# ansible add pub key client to a third machine

Tags: ansible

I have about 100 machines that are being controlled via ansible, how to configure via playbook the 100 machines to add they keys to a third server, so the clients can ssh via pub key into a third machine. This to be done via playbook
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : https://gitlab.com/ananya26nov/k8-vms-on-kvm-ansible/-/blob/master/roles/ssh_keypair_role/tasks/main.yml

hosts

```
[existing_vms]
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.3
.
.100

[nodes]
192.168.0.101
```

playbook

```
- hosts: existing_vms
  name: Play3 - Configure passwordless ssh from existing_vms to new_vm nodes
  vars:
    sudo_user: <username>
    key_folder: /home/<username>/.ssh
    key_name: id_rsa
    ssh_password_of_nodes: my_password
  roles:
      - ssh_keypair_role
```

command
`ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts -u <user> --private-key <key_path> --extra-vars "sudo_user=<desired_sudo_user_name> ssh_password_of_nodes=<existing_vms_password>"`